# QT qDeleteAll and new afterwards same memory address and crash

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a weird behavior when using qDeleteAll on a QMap<QString, Record*>.
First I delete my values in the QMap with qDeleteAll and then I use m_data.clear()
to empty the QMap.

```
void ClassName::function1(QMap<QString, QString> filter)
{
    qDebug() << "function1 called";
    QString query = "postgrestAdress?";
    if (filter.size()){
        for (QMap<QString, QString>::iterator i = filter.begin(); i != filter.end(); i++ ) {
            query.append("&").append(i.key()).append("=").append(i.value());
        }
    }

    postgrestLambdaFucntion(query,[this, query](QList<QMap<QString,QString>> result)
    {
        qDeleteAll(m_data);

        m_data.clear();
        m_users.clear();

        for(auto &line : result)
        {
            Record *record = Mapper::mapQMapToRecord(line);
            qDebug() << "created Record:" << record << " with id:" << record->id;
            m_data.insert(line.value("material_number")+ "_" +QString::number(record->id), record);
            if (!m_users.contains(line.value("user"))){
                m_users.append(line.value("user"));
            }
        }
        nextFunction(0);
    });
}
```

Consider this as a record:

```
class Record : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Record(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent){};
    ~Record() {
        qDebug() << "record " << this << "with id" << this->id << " is destroyed";
    };

    int id = 0;
    QString material_number = "";
    QString user = "";
}
```

When I call function1 with an already populated m_data list I get this debug information:

```
>Returing table from postgrest...
>record  Record(0x564813686040) with id 1  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x5648136f74b0) with id 33  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x56481376a6b0) with id 15  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x564813708c00) with id 43  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x564813c28090) with id 44  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x564813768eb0) with id 2  is destroyed
>record  Record(0x5648136eb7a0) with id 14  is destroyed
>created Record: Record(0x564813768eb0)  with id: 15
>created Record: Record(0x564813c28090)  with id: 2
>created Record: Record(0x564813708c00)  with id: 43
>created Record: Record(0x56481376a6b0)  with id: 33
>created Record: Record(0x5648136f74b0)  with id: 14
>created Record: Record(0x564813686040)  with id: 1
>created Record: Record(0x564813de45b0)  with id: 44
```

Inside the Mapper-Function I create new Record-Classes

```
Record* Mapper::mapQMapToRecord(QMap<QString, QString> line)
{

    Record* record = new Record(nullptr);
    record->id = line.value("id").toInt();
    record->user = line.value("user");
    return record;

}
```

Note that the Memory-Address of those new created objects are the same
as the ones qDeleteAll removed.
In the next function I make more requests and add data to the records,
which are now "not available" and I get nullptr exceptions.

If I don't use "qDeleteAll" it works.
I can also use a for-loop and use "deleteLater" from QObject
without errors.
I just want to know this behaviour better or why it happens.
(it happens in debug and release builds)

Anybody has insights for me?

Best Regards

exa.byte

Comment: Concerning _Note that the Memory-Address of those new created objects are the same as the ones qDeleteAll removed._ There are chances that the released memory is re-used for new allocations - especially if the new are of same type like the previously deleted ones.

Comment: How memory is managed surely depends on the OS and/or the used C++ / C runtime library. (I consider that C++ heap memory management may build upon that of C.) As you asked for insights one FYI: [glibc Wiki - Overview of Malloc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals). Please, note that there are managed internally multiple kinds of bins (to achieve less fragmentation). This is IMHO a very common technique. Therefore my hint that things of same type may allocated at similar addresses -> they go into the same bin.

Comment: Did you use debugger to see on which exact line it crashes? What was the error message? What were the values of the variables when the crash occurred?

Comment: Another thing: does `Record` need to inherit from `QObject`? I do not say that this is the cause  of the crash, but you should keep you code as simple as possible. And inheriting from `QObject` is a "big thing" for a class which has lots of consequences (uncopiable, may have parent, children, metadata, signals, properties etc.)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers.
I used the record as a struct before, but i am fairly new with pointers and thought is has something to do with that. 
The programm crashes with a sigsev signal.
The debugger stops at qstring.h line 1094: i
nline QString::QString(const QString &other) noexcept : d(other.d)
{ Q_ASSERT(&other != this); d->ref.ref(); }

the last debug-info is printed is when I open the next request to an API over NetworkAcessManager. But the result is never received.
My guess is, that the table-view still wants to render old data but before it's notified its emtpied.

Comment: Reading my answer I just got the idea why its crashing.
The m_data QMAP is used in the Provider and also the in the QTableModelView
When doing my requests and delete the m_data values and objects the ModelView wants to use these objects to render the View.
There is a short timespan when the TableView is visible before all requests are finished.
Now it tries to access the deleted objects again to render the grid...
I use "beginResetModel()" when all requests are finished ...
Sorry for bothering you all :)
thanks for your help!

Comment: I meant where IN YOUR CODE does the crash occur. Of course the call stack goes deeper into `QString` etc. But never mind because as I understand you are using the copy of the map somewhere else (i.e. the map got detached and there are two or more independent copies of the map), then of course deleting the pointers and clearing one map will leave the other maps untouched, but full of pointers which point to deleted objects. Hence the crash.

Comment: I guess you are came to C++ from languages like Java, C# or Python... But C++ is different. If has so called "value semantics". So if you call `map = another_map;` then then the map gets copied. (however it is shallow copy, not deep copy) It is not like in the above mentioned languages, where the both identifiers `map` and `another_map` refer to the same object and if you change content in one, it will also change content of the other one. Note that with Qt this is even more complicated, the maps do not get copied unless you access them with non-const methods... this is called copy-on-write.

Comment: Hello V.K.
That was the problkem, i coudln't figure out a line inside this code-fragment which leads to a crash. You you could say it's the line "nextFunction(0)" which first does a request with QNetworkAccessManager and then before the finished-signal arrives the crash happens.
I then realised it's because the frontend switches back the table-view where the data then is empty and therefore a call to data(Qt::Role...) fails since it can't access the object in its own m_data container which held the same record-pointers...
tricky  to find out, but asking here and commenting helped me out:)